# How to clone only one project instead of cloning a directory in bitbucket?

Tags: git, bitbucket, bitbucket-server

Clone only one project not branch in bitbucket. How can i do that using git commands in bitbucket repository?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any way to clone a git repository's sub-directory only?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/600079/is-there-any-way-to-clone-a-git-repositorys-sub-directory-only)

Comment: You seem to be confused by terminology. Branches are not directories.